# Get the frame of the keyboard dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, uitextview

Is it possible to get the frame, actually its height, of the keyboard dynamically? As I have a `UITextView` and I would like to adjust its height according to the keyboard frame height, when the input method of the keyboard is changed. As you know, different input methods may have different keyboard frame height.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

try this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                         name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                       object:nil];

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{

// Get the size of the keyboard.
CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

//Given size may not account for screen rotation
int height = MIN(keyboardSize.height,keyboardSize.width);
int width = MAX(keyboardSize.height,keyboardSize.width);

//your other code here..........
}
```

[Tutorial for more information](http://iosdevelopertip.blogspot.in/2014/10/scroll-uitextfield-above-keyboard-in.html)

Comment: This is particularly useful when working with with different height/type keyboards in iOS8. Until now, simply hardcoding 216 (portrait) would do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: For swift users out there: use `let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue().size`

Comment: You should probably use `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` instead. I don't think it matters for `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`, but if you change it to `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` you will get some weird bugs because the frame will be the before state, not the after state.

Comment: Better way is to use optional chaining:
 if let keyboardSize: CGSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size {
      print("Keyboard size: \(keyboardSize)")
}

Answer (score 7):

Just follow this tutorial from Apple and you will get what you want. [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7). In order to determine the area covered by keyboard please refer to this [tutorial](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/07/calculating-area-covered-by-keyboard/).

Comment: But how could i detect the input method change action?

Comment: If you are the programmer then you should know which Input soft keyboard has been opened by you at any given time.

Comment: I wish I know, but i couldn't. If you know how to detect the input method change action and get height of the current keyboard, could you please kindly let me know. I really appreciate it:)

Comment: It's textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange to grab the input character. I use this when entering dollar amounts and I don't want the use to use anything but decimals

Comment: You should provide some code as example, because the day the links become invalid, the answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 2):

For the Swift 3 users, the @Hector code (with some additions) would be:

In your `viewDidLoad` add the observer :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardDidShow(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardDidShow , object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardDidHide(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardDidHide , object: nil)
```

Then implement those methods:

```
func keyboardDidShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {
     print("Keyboard will show!")
     // print(notification.userInfo)

     let keyboardSize:CGSize = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.size
     print("Keyboard size: \(keyboardSize)")  

     let height = min(keyboardSize.height, keyboardSize.width)
     let width = max(keyboardSize.height, keyboardSize.width)

}

func keyboardDidHide(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        print("Keyboard will hide!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to the view which contains the text field in Swift 3. This will make the text field animate up and down with the keyboard.

```
private var keyboardIsVisible = false
private var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0.0

// MARK: Notifications

private func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
private func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

// MARK: Triggered Functions

@objc private func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    keyboardIsVisible = true
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else {
        return
    }
    if let keyboardHeight = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.height {
        self.keyboardHeight = keyboardHeight
    }
    if !textField.isHidden {
        if let duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber,
            let curve = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber {
            animateHUDWith(duration: duration.doubleValue,
                           curve: UIViewAnimationCurve(rawValue: curve.intValue) ?? UIViewAnimationCurve.easeInOut,
                           toLocation: calculateTextFieldCenter())
        }
    }
}

@objc private func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification) {
    keyboardIsVisible = false
    if !self.isHidden {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else {
            return
        }
        if let duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber,
            let curve = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber {
            animateHUDWith(duration: duration.doubleValue,
                           curve: UIViewAnimationCurve(rawValue: curve.intValue) ?? UIViewAnimationCurve.easeInOut,
                           toLocation: calculateTextFieldCenter())
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Helpers

private func animateHUDWith(duration: Double, curve: UIViewAnimationCurve, toLocation location: CGPoint) {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(TimeInterval(duration))
    UIView.setAnimationCurve(curve)
    textField.center = location
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

private func calculateTextFieldCenter() -> CGPoint {
    if !keyboardIsVisible {
        return self.center
    } else {
        let yLocation = (self.view.frame.height - keyboardHeight) / 2
        return CGPoint(x: self.center.x, y: yLocation)
    }
}
```