# Cursor disappears under keyboard in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

When entering text into a UITextView, if you type enough lines or hit return enough times, the cursor will naturally go under the keyboard. Certain apps, such as the Apple Notes app, handle this just fine, scrolling the textview until the cursor is visible again. I have struggled to replicate this behavior. I've had no luck with `textView.scrollRangeToVisible()` with the selectedRange or `textView.scrollRectToVisible()` with the caret rect.

Some other things I've tried:

- http://inessential.com/2014/01/07/uitextview_scroll-to-typing_bug
- https://gist.github.com/DanielTomlinson/802b54f04dc0c4afe56a

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would try the following steps:

1. Make the `UITextView`'s fill the entire height of the screen
2. Get the Keyboard Height Dynamically(See: [Get the frame of the keyboard dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989306/get-the-frame-of-the-keyboard-dynamically)) This is especially important with the release of third party keyboards in iOS 8.
3. Then when the cursor goes below the keyboard, move the UITextView up by the screen height minus the keyboard height.

Comment: Will this work of my textView is not the entire height of the screen?