# "Send Message" not visible when keyboard comes up

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, constraints

I am trying to implement a very basic chat feature into my app and I am using constraints to keep everything in the correct place. It is great except for when I need to actually type, and the problem that arises is that the keyboard covers the text field and I not only cannot see the textfield but I cannot dismiss it. Thank you for all help!

In summary,

- Using a textfield with contraints at bottom of screen
- keyboard shows up and covers it, and I cannot dismiss the keyboard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Answer (score 1):

Just set observers for *UIKeyboardWillShowNotification* and *UIKeyboardWillHideNotification*.

Whenever, *UIKeyboardWillShowNotification* is triggered, move the UITextfield upwards equivalent to the keyboard height. Then, when the *UIKeyboardWillHideNotification* is triggered, move the keyboard back into place.

Comment: how do you get the keyboard height? @7Vikram7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989306/get-the-frame-of-the-keyboard-dynamically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874975/cant-get-correct-value-of-keyboard-height-in-ios8

Comment: @Ryan Refer these 2

Comment: both of those are in Objective-C

Comment: NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil) //////////// func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {
    let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame:NSValue = userInfo.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.CGRectValue()
    let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
}

Answer (score 1):

Dismiss keyboard by tapping anywhere

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)}

func dismissKeyboard() 
{
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: this does not solve the issue of not seeing the text but is a very helpful snippet of code because I did not know how to do that

Comment: now ur keyboard is going down or not?? by tapping outside??

Comment: you have to use the constraints very well to show textfield. Use priorities in the constraint. I think you can do that easily or make the page scrollable.